# Pasar formulario como objeto a una clase

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una clase para limpiar los controles de mi formulario, esta clase esta en mi capa de servicios, misma que tengo referenciada en mi capa de presentacion, pero no encuetro como pasar el nombre del formulario a mi clase, tampoco me da ningun error.

NOTA: Cabe mencionar que es la primera vez que estoy tratando de usar el desarrollo por capas MVP.

Esta es la clase en mi capa de servicios:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Services
{
    public class Helper
    {
        public static void ClearFormControls(Form form)
        {
            foreach(Control control in form. Controls)
            {
                if(control is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)control;
                    txtbox.Text = string. Empty;
                }
                else if(control is ComboBox)
                {
                    ComboBox cmbbox = (ComboBox)control;
                    cmbbox.Text = string. Empty;
                }
                else if (control is CheckBox)
                {
                    CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)control;
                    chkbox.Checked = false;
                }
                else if (control is RadioButton)
                {
                    RadioButton rdbtn = (RadioButton)control;
                    rdbtn.Checked = false;
                }
                else if (control is DateTimePicker)
                {
                    DateTimePicker dtp = (DateTimePicker)control;
                    dtp.Value = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Desde el boton de mi formulario llamo a mi clase:

```cs
private void iconButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Helper.ClearFormControls(this);
}
```

**Apertura del formulario hijo:**

```
private void btnData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActivateButton(sender, RGBColors.color1);
        OpenChildForm(new FormDataImport());
    }
```

Como puedo pasar el formulario como objeto a la clase?

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda que se me pueda brindar.

Saludos

DS

Comment: Cómo pasar el formulario como objeto a la clase? A través del constructor? Puedes también crear una propiedad del mismo tipo base del objeto que quieres pasar, para hacerlo reusable, y luego llamar al método que limpia los campos. Aquí estoy adivinando. Cuál EXACTAMENTE es el resultado que esperas, cuál EXACTAMENTE es el resultado que estás obteniendo? Ya intentaste depurarlo?

Comment: @Arriel
Lo quie quiero precisamente es eso reutilizar mi clase Helper desde cualquier formulario.
Si he depurado no obtengo ningun error.

Comment: Entonces, cuál es tu pregunta? Por qué no le pasas el form a tu clase? Puedes tener un campo para mantener la referencia: `private Form _form;` y luego `SetForm(Form form){ _form = form)};` y luego llamas a `CleanForm(){ MetodoQueLimpia(_form)}`. No entiendo cómo esperas que te apoyemos. Qué tiene de malo el código que presentas?

Answer (score 1):

EL hecho de haberlo movido a una clase Helper con un método estático ya está logrando lo que quieres. Poder reutilizarlo desde cualquier otro formulario exactamente de la manera que ya lo estás haciendo.

Pero para mejorarlo un poco podrías hacer uso de una característica de C# llamada métodos de extensión que te permite llamar a métodos estáticos como si fueran parte de la clase original.

Para lograrlo simplemente agrégale `this` al primer (y único) argumento de tu método y agrégale el modificador `static` a la clase `Helper`
En este caso puedes dejar tu código así.

```cs
namespace Services
{
    public static class Helper
    {
        public static void ClearFormControls(this Form form)
        {
            //... el mismo código que tenías antes o si quieres lo puedes simplificar así:
            foreach (var control in form.Controls)
            {
                switch (control)
                {
                    case ComboBox comboBox: comboBox.Text = String.Empty; break;
                    case CheckBox checkBox: checkBox.Checked = false; break;
                    case RadioButton radioButton: radioButton.Checked = false; break;
                    case DateTimePicker dateTimePicker: dateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now; break;
                    case Control controlWithText: controlWithText.Text = string.Empty; break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

y luego simplemente llamarlo así

```
private void iconButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ClearFormControls();
}
```

Comment: Hice las modificaciones que me mencionas pero por alguna razón no funciona, tendra que ver que abro el formulario dentro del formulario padre?
Agregue como abro el formulario hijo dentro del padre.

Comment: Dentro del formulario hijo tengo un control TabPage, no se si algo tenga esto que ver.

Comment: Revisando con mas detalle en el Switch se va directo a la ultima línea:
case Control controlWithText: controlWithText.Text = string.Empty; break;
Y en el formulario si tengo varios controles ComboBox y TextBox.
Alguna idea que puede estar mal?

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado solo cambie esta linea:

De:

```
public static void ClearFormControls(this Form form)
    {
        foreach(var control in form.Controls)
```

A:

```
public static void ClearChildControls( this Control parentControl )
    {
        foreach( Control control in parentControl.Controls )
```

Gracias por la ayuda brindada.

DS